# Jquery draggable to relatively positioned parent container

Tags: jquery, draggable, css-position

Please look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/MbYq6/

Once you drag a blue marker and place it on the map, the marker repositions itself to an offset value. I don't know where is the cooardinates coming from.

The marker should be position absolute in its parent container whose position attribute is relative.

Please let me know if anyone bumped into the same and solved it.

Thank you
SamS